# Javascript "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" error

Tags: javascript

When i run this code it gives a syntax error in Chrome.

```
var leanboo = confirm("RFT(ready for testing)?") // Co1,Cr1
console.log(leanboo)
var text = prompt("What are your thoughts of this Area?")
console.log(text)

function crashCourseTesterIdGenerator(min, max) {
console.log(Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);)
} //Co1,Cr2
var testermin = prompt("Id generating min:")
var testermax = prompt("Id generating max:")
console.log(crashCourseTesterIdGenerator(testermin, testermax))
```

Does it have to do with the method name length or am i just forgetting some semicolons?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typographic error.


Comment: @Pointy, but you still answered it anyway? Kind of defeats the purpose of dissuading newcomers to post this type of question if you're just going to answer it anyway.

Comment: @maček well the point of closing "typo questions" is that they don't do anybody any good as a long-term reference question, but this person still had a problem to be solved. I suppose I could have just typed a comment. I didn't put a lot of deep thought into the situation :)

Comment: Aside from the obvious syntax error, presumably you have put the `console.log` there to see why it's not working - if it isn't obvious the function has no return statement.

Comment: [jslint.com](http://jslint.com) or [jshint.com](http://jshint.com) or use your debugger which will point you to the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a `;` **inside** the `console.log()` call in that function.

Comment: Thanks! (Can't upvote your answer because of the 15 reputation limit...)

Answer (score 1):

```
var leanboo = confirm("RFT(ready for testing)?"); // Co1,Cr1
console.log(leanboo);
var text = prompt("What are your thoughts of this Area?");
console.log(text);

function crashCourseTesterIdGenerator(min, max) {
console.log(Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min));
} //Co1,Cr2
var testermin = prompt("Id generating min:");
var testermax = prompt("Id generating max:");
console.log(crashCourseTesterIdGenerator(testermin, testermax));
```

Should fix ya right up.

Answer (score 0):

Semi colons go at the end of each statement in Javascript. You're missing them.

They're not strictly *required*, but you can commit all kinds of hard-to-find errors without them where Javascript doesn't know when one statement ends and another begins. Best to make it a matter of personal law to always use them and you're future self will save lots of debugging time.

And then you have an extra one:

```
console.log(Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);)
```

before the end of the line. Which is actually causing the error message.

Comment: So where i searched 'js randomizing between numbers' didn't know that... But thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: @avaragecoder There is a depressing amount of really badly programmed example Javascript code around. Be careful of copying stuff from random sites. Because Javascript is often used by non-programmers, who hack and share code around, the quality is often terrible. If you can, get hold of Douglas Crockford's book on Javascript, he shows how it should be used in a safe and professional manner, that will give you a good foundation, at least.